# What is the best way to get svg from png?

Tags: image, svg

I'm interested in the question of how I get .svg image from png?

Comment: `potrace` would be my suggestion. Available on `macOS` via `homebrew` with `brew install potrace`.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [CloudConvert](http://cloudconvert.com), sign up for their free account, and convert away.